# Restrict database access to views in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to force the usage of a custom view and permit reading db data without using the view?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're attempting to do? You want to restrict a user to only use a view to access the database or you want to control document writes via a design document?

Comment: Of cause! I want to restrict document read by design documents. The user should only have read access when he f.e. provide the correct document id.